# Creating images that change with other object onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my complete test HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Table</title>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Untitled_1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="sidebar">
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Table</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a rel="img1">Link1</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a rel="img2">Link2</a>
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box">
    <img src="cant-believe-it-icon.png" id="img1"/>
    <img src="too-much-icon.png" id="img2"/>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

There is no CSS for this test page, and here is the entire .js file:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    imgid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('img').hide();    
    $('#'+imgid).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

When this is run in jsfiddle (without the head, body, html tags, etc.) it works fine - when one of the s are clicked, one image shows up and the other doesn't. However, when the entire code is put in microsoft expressions web and previewed, nothing happens when the links are clicked. Is this a problem with my linking of the .js file to the html? and how should I fix this?

Comment: For extra help, when run in jsfiddle, until one of the <td>s are clicked, both images are visible. How do I set it so that at the start, only the first image is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your scripts at the end of the `body` tag or place your code in a window onload event.

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
      imgid = $(this).attr('rel');
      $('a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      $('img').hide();    
      $('#'+imgid).fadeIn('slow');
    });
})
```

[From jQuery docs](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Comment: But I thought I could just have an external file and link to it in the <head>?

Comment: Yes, but that means your script will be loaded before the DOM exists, so you won't find any `a` tag to bind your click event.

Comment: Ah I see, how do I add a window onload event to the javascript as I was given the code to use in another question (I don't know javascript or jQuery)?

Comment: So my .js file should read $( window ).load(function() {all of my previous code}) ?

Comment: You're right, thank you so much. Do you how I could get it so that only the first image is visible before a link is clicked?

Comment: What if I want to add more images later? Would I d that for each of the images, or is there a cleaner way to hide them all?

Comment: Try it yourself first, that way you will learn a lot more. If you bump to some problems later just ask another question on this site.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, I need to learn javascript and jQuery soon anyway.